# Require a file in the current directory without setting load-path

Tags: load-path, require

I have test code that wants to `require` some utility code in the same directory.  I would prefer to not update the `load-path`, as most of the time, I do not want me or any other user who has checked out this code to be looking in this directory.

It seemed that `(require 'utils "./utils.el")` should work, but this gives me an error:

```
file-remote-p: Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, ./utils.el
```

Is there a better way than something like

```
(let ((load-path (append (list (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name))))
                         load-path)))
    (require 'utils))
```

I also cannot specify an absolute path, as the path may be different when other users check out the repository.

Comment: Have you tried `expand-file-name`?

Comment: You could also try load-file instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like John Kitchin pointed out, load-file does what you want. For example:

```
(setq my-utils-file "utils.el")
(load-file 
  (expand-file-name my-utils-file
                    (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name))))
```